# Reduce cache size of flash storage devices

Tags: linux, usb, cache, storage, flash-memory

For various benefits Linux uses a memory cache for writes to removable stogare devices like memory sticks. This cache seems to be quite large on my system, which leads to some annoying behavior. For instance, when I copy an image to the stick, it finishes within seconds, but the following `sync` takes a couple of minutes, with no process indication. This also makes it harder to do speed measurements or similar things.

I know I can disable the cache with `mount -o sync`, but as I understand, this is not recommended for flash storage devices. I cannot use `mount -o flush` because that only works with FAT file systems.

However a simple solution would be to just reduce the cache size to, say, 1 MB. Then `sync` will always take no longer than a few seconds and when copying large files with tools like `pv` they would actually show reasonable values (for process bar, transfer speed etc.).

Is there a way to configure the cache size in Linux?

Comment: You can adjust this system wide with the `vm.dirty_expire_centisecs` sysctl param. However I do not know of a way to do this per-mount. There's a good explanation of what's going on here: http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/linux-pdflush.htm