# Linux USB Flash direct write / write cache

Tags: fedora, usb-drive, cache, write

Lately I've been using USB2 flash drives to transfer a lot of data to my company.

When copying the Data to the flash drive, I noticed that the data is not written directly to the drive. It wrote with 200MB/sec to cache(?). I then `umount` or `sync` the drive and it takes hours to actually write the data to the 
drive.

I also tried using `cp` instead of Nautilus, but it had the same behavior. `dd` is not an option for copying normal files.

Is there any way to make Linux write the data directly without caching when writing on USB storage? Or maybe reduce caching so that I don't have to wait for hours when unmounting the drive?

What's annoying me most is that the progress bar finishes copying and I then have to wait a unspecified time for `sync` to write the data.

I'm on a Fedora 25 machine.

*[Update] Tried to clarify my question.*

*[Update 2] Found a similar question without answer:[Reduce cache size of flash storage devices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141031/reduce-cache-size-of-flash-storage-devices?rq=1)*

Comment: Maybe calling `sync` after `cp` can be useful? You'd wait for that to finish.

Comment: I've tried with sync. It's the same behavior as with umount, as it writes the data after the copy process. It is really annoying when you see the progress bar finished and then have to wait a undefined time before you can remove the flash drive. I don't mind waiting for a while when writing >10GB of data to a USB2 device. It's just annoying not to know how long it will take and when it really is finished. The only thing I like about windows where the caching is less of a problem.

Comment: There is an answer here, which affects the entire system not just removable devices, but a number of desktop users have found it useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292024/how-to-reduce-linux-write-buffer-for-removable-devices

Comment: Although, some of the claims in the linked LWN.net article are very suspicious IMO. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480399/why-were-usb-stick-stall-problems-reported-in-2013-why-wasnt-this-problem-so

Comment: I too find it annoying. however, i do watch the progress after issuing <code>umount</code> with <code>watch -n 5 iostat /dev/your device </code>'

Comment: There is a `sync` mount option. If it is auto-mounting, I don't know where the config is. There is also a command (I think `unbuffer`, that  can run other commands with no caching. None will make it faster, it will slow the writes, and speed up the unmount. Over all it will be a little slower, but safer.

Answer (score -4):

You could dry the direct `dd` method.
Sounds like it's time to reformat your drive with: `mk2fs.` -fs-of-your-choice.

`man mkf2s`

The dd route is simple.

Run once before you pulug in your drive.

`lsblk`

And once after.

Notice the output of your device.

Then to copy the files you can create a new device like so:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=~/my-files.dd.img bs=1G
mkfs.ext4 ~/my-files.dd.img
losetup /dev/loop0 ~/my-files.dd.img`

**Note
If you’d like this to be remounted after a machine reboot then add the above line to the rc.local file.
`vi /etc/rc.local`**

Mount the device with:

`mkdir /mnt/amazing
mount -o loop=/dev/loop0 ~/my-files.dd.img /mnt/mymountpoint`

To check the file has been mounted you can use the df command:

`` df -h | grep mymountpoint
/dev/loop0  976M  1.3M  924M  1% /mnt/mymountpoint
where `bs=` a value greater than the output of:
`ls -lh ./your-file-here` ``

When you're done unmount the devices:

`umount /mnt/mymountpoint
losetup -d /dev/loop0`

Haven't tested this but I suppose this is how it should work.

Cheers
rivanov

Comment: Hi. I don't really understand your answer. Fist of all I don't know why i should create a image file? I did reformat my usb-flash-drive many times because of the cache write the filesystem got corrupted. I even zeroed the first 1024 blocks of the device because it had a ISO written on it and the ISO Label wouldn't go away with simply reformatting. And writing on the device with dd without oflag=direct is also cached.

Comment: try using `wipefs /dev/yourdev`

Comment: Writing with `dd` won't bypass the OS cache ...

Comment: @dirkt perhaps I did not understand the OPs question and rushed to answer.

Comment: @GeraldZehetner I don't understand your problem mate. Could you provide more specifics?

Comment: He wants to *monitor* the completeness of writing to the USB flash drive. His idea was to *disable buffering*, so `cp` only returns when all data is *really* written to USB flash, and not when it has been buffered. Or one could use `pv` etc. The problem with that is of course that disabling buffering will cause duplicate writes for inodes/FAT. Making an image with `dd`, and mounting it on loop etc. has *nothing* to do with this question. In your place, I'd delete this answer ...

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. What @dirkt wrote is exactly what I want. I konw that completly disabling the write buffer / cache is not ideal, maybe there is a way to just reduce the buffer size?